# Pydantic 2 Pandas Timestamp / NaT migration issue

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, pydantic

I am migrating from Pydantic 1 to 2 and having issues getting this code to work.

Expected result is that 'NaT' string would be converted to pd.NaT and exist in the model.

Minimal working example:

```
from typing import Union

import pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
import pandas as pd


class CheckTimestamp(BaseModel):
    ts: pd.Timestamp

    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)

    @pydantic.field_validator('ts', mode='before')
    def convert_to_timestamp(value: Union[str, pd.Timestamp]):
        """coming from the cache, this value can sometimes be "NaT" string, convert into pd.NaT so it doesn't error"""
        if value == "NaT":
            return pd.NaT
        return pd.Timestamp(value)


sample_model = CheckTimestamp(ts='NaT')
```

This code raises the following validation error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d53542\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\232.8660.197\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\d53542\Documents\python\Analytics.OperationAnalytics-lib\virtual_environments\parsing_test\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 159, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CheckTimestamp
ts
  Input should be an instance of Timestamp [type=is_instance_of, input_value=NaT, input_type=NaTType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1/v/is_instance_of
```

I believe the issue is that pydantic v2 is more picky and is treating the pd.NaT as a different object than pd.Timestamp. I have tried unioning classes but I am obviously missing something.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the correct way to type the pandas NaT

```
from typing import Union

import pandas as pd
from pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype import NaTType


class CheckTimestamp(BaseModel):
    ts: Union[pd.Timestamp, NaTType]
```

Adding this NaTType buried within pandas fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue since pydantic v2 with another custom datatype. I had it adapted for your case like so:

```py
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd

from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema
from pydantic import GetCoreSchemaHandler, GetJsonSchemaHandler
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue

class CheckTimestamp(pd.Timestamp):

    @classmethod
    def validate_timestamp(cls, v: Any) -> pd.Timestamp:
        if isinstance(v, pd.Timestamp):
            return v

        s = str(v)
        try:
            return pd.Timestamp(s)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Invalid pandas timestamp")

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, source_type, _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler) -> CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.no_info_after_validator_function(
            cls.validate_timestamp,
            core_schema.str_schema(),
            serialization=core_schema.to_string_ser_schema()
        )

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, _core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        return handler(core_schema.str_schema())


sample_model = CheckTimestamp('NaT')
```

Tell me if this works in any of your cases.

Comment: In short this does not work as I would expect since I want CheckTimestamp.ts -> pd.NaT. Would this be used as the input type if I have many other fields in the model? Like this:

class CheckTimestamp(BaseModel):
    ts: CheckTimestamp
    name: str

Comment: Well you can use it as a field in a Pydantic class object, yes.